# When $P(x)$ is divided by $βx + α$, the remainder is $P(-α/β)$, why?

Tags: polynomials

I understand the remainder theorem, when the polynomial $P(x)$ is divided by $x-α$, the quotient is $Q(x)$ and the remainder is $R$, then
$P(\alpha) = R$.

The Cambridge textbook also highlights that when $P(x)$ is divided by $βx + α$, the remainder is $P(-α/β)$. Could you please show me the proof of this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write

$$P(x) = (\beta x + \alpha) \cdot Q(x) + R$$

where $Q(x)$ is the quotient and $R$ is the remainder (and a constant).

Substituting $- \frac{\alpha}{\beta}$ in place of $x$, we get$^*$

$$\begin{align*}
P\left (- \frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right ) &= \left (\beta \cdot - \frac{\alpha}{\beta} + \alpha\right ) \cdot Q\left (- \frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right ) + R \\[0.3cm]
&= R
\end{align*}$$

---

$^*$ It's worth pointing out that $\alpha / \beta$ is the root of the linear binomial $\beta x + \alpha$ (the divisor).

Answer (score 4):

Well, when dividing $P(x)$ by $\beta x + \alpha$, we write $P(x) = (\beta x + \alpha)Q(x) + R$. You just have to notice that $-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$ is a root of the monomial $\beta x + \alpha$ and then $P\left(-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right) = 0\cdot Q\left(-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right) + R = R$.